# Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi there are already lots of threads related to this problem.
But still i got stuck into the same . When I am trying to access this REST api, I couldnt able to get the response. I cannot control server side response header because its public API .can any body help on this.

Below is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#medication").autocomplete({
        select : function(request, response) {
        //$(this).value(response.item.value);
        getMedicationIdByName(response.item.value);
    },
    search  : function(){$(this).addClass('working');},
    open    : function(){$(this).removeClass('working');},

    source : function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({

            headers : {
                        Accept : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        "Content-Type" : "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            },
            type : "GET",
            url : "http://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/spellingsuggestions",
            data : "name="+ request.term,
            crossDomain: 'true',
            dataFil ter : function(data) {
                return data;
            },

            success : function(data) {
                try {
                        //alert("success!!"+JSON.stringify(data));

                        data = data.suggestionGroup.suggestionList["suggestion"]+ "";
                        data = data.split(",");

                        response($.map(data,function(item) {
                            //alert("success!!"+JSON.stringify(item))
                            return {
                                    value : item
                            };
                        }));
                } catch (e) {
                    alert(e);
                }

            },
            error : function() {
                alert('Cannot connect to REST API!!!');
            }
        });
    },
    minLength : 4
    });
});
```

Comment: What is it, *specifically*, that you still don't understand about this having read the dozens of other questions -- and more importantly their answers -- about this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `dataType` to `jsonp` in your ajax request.

```
type: "GET",
headers: { 
    Accept : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
},
url: "http://rxnav.nlm.nih.gov/REST/spellingsuggestions",
data: { name: "bard"},
dataType: "jsonp",
crossdomain: true,
```

Comment: Hi thanks for reply , I already tried above. but it returns xml response . what i want is JSON response from server

Comment: This solves Access-Control-Allow-Origin problem that you were having. I don't know this API so I'm not sure how (or even if) it supports `json` responses.  Some APIs require you to add `.json` onto the end of the request or something similar.